# Using a different port for SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl

We are using a node.js app on Ubuntu box that requires a SSL on a specific port. We're using port 8081 for our node.js script but my understanding is that I need to set up the port for listening. I have edited the ports.conf file and currently listening on that port but our app says the port is not available. So the question is, how can my app use a SSL port if the port needs to be listening?

The ports.conf file:

```
    <IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
    Listen 44567
    Listen 8081
    </IfModule>
```

The default-ssl.conf file:

```
    VirtualHost _default_:8081
    ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog $APACHE_LOG_DIR/error.log
    CustomLog $APACHE_LOG_DIR/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/privatekey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-certs/bundle.crt
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    VirtualHost
```

It's a Ubuntu box with node.js.

The objective here is to have my node script using port 8081 for their SSL component but app keeps saying port is not available.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you include the relevant portion of the configuration files and clarify what your stack here is? Is this a pure python app or are you using a framework? Add the relevant stack related tags to your question. Review this guide for further tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just changed it. Forgive me, I'm new to this site but I think I got the question right now.